# My code gets the error expected ')'

Tags: cs50

I have tried to look for any curly brackets or parenthesis that don't have a pair but I can't find anything. Please let me know if you find the error or any other errors. The code is supposed to take the amount of minutes you take in the shower and turn it into the amount of bottles or water you used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>


int main(void)

{
printf("Minutes: ");
int minutes = get_int();

if (minutes >0)
{ 
    int bottles = (128*(1.5*minutes)/16);
    printf("Bottles:%i \n "bottles);
}
else 
{
    printf("Please type in a positive integer\n");
}


}
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

For every printf statement in C, if you reference variables in your print statement, you will have to use % identifiers in your print statement, followed by a comma and the variables you are referencing.

In the code you have provided, there error comes from missing a comma following the print statement you have:

```
printf("Bottles:%i \n ", bottles);
```

%i - this means you will print an integer value that reference after the comma

bottles - is the integer variable that is being referenced

Answer (score 0):

Do u miss something in this line?

```
    printf("Bottles:%i \n "bottles);
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: i think, you forgot "," between " and bottles

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

this?

```
 printf("Bottles:%i \n ", bottles);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16369839)

Comment: Noted and thanks. I will make answer long next time.

Answer (score 0):

printf("Bottles:%i \n ",bottles);

add the missing comma

Answer (score 0):

You should use , (comma) while passing values in printf.

`printf("Bottles:%i \n ", bottles);`

So the final code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>


int main(void)

{
    printf("Minutes: ");
    int minutes = get_int();

    if (minutes >0)
    {
        int bottles = (128*(1.5*minutes)/16);
        printf("Bottles:%i \n ", bottles);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Please type in a positive integer\n");
    }


}
```